# Reversing LinkedList result in wrong links by recursion

Tags: c++, linked-list

I wrote the following code to reverse a linked list recursively for my homework. However, It's not connecting the links properly. Can please someone tell me what's wrong in the following reverse function? I have tried GDB as well. But, could not figure out what's wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
    int data;
    Node *next;
    explicit Node(int data)
    {
        this->data = data;
        next = nullptr;
    }
};

void pushBack(Node * &head, Node * &tail, int data)
{
    if(head == nullptr)
    {
        head = new Node(data);
        tail = head;
    }

    else
    {
        tail->next = new Node(data);
        tail = tail->next;
    }
}

void printList(Node *head)
{
    if(head == nullptr)
        return;
    cout << head->data << " ";
    printList(head->next);
}


void reverseListRecursive(Node * &head)
{
    if(head->next == nullptr)
    {
        return;
    }

    reverseListRecursive(head->next);

    head->next->next = head;
    head->next = nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    int cap;
    cin >> cap;
    Node *head = nullptr, *tail = nullptr;
    for(int i = 0; i < cap; ++i)
    {
        int element;
        cin >> element;
        pushBack(head, tail, element);
    }

    reverseListRecursive(head);
    printList(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Head is being passed by reference and also the infinite recursion is also not there.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Program just sits there and waits for input.

Comment: A side note about GDB: the correct usage if to step through the code where you suspect the error is  instruction by instruction while keeping an eye out for the unexpected, like the program storing the wrong value or taking the wrong path. The unexpected is almost always a bug.

Comment: What's wrong is that the reversing algorithm is fundamentally wrong. There is no single mistake or a typo, the algorithm is fundamentally flawed and must be reimplemented. You can prove to yourself that the algorithm is fundamentally flawed by observing a simple fact that, once reversed, the linked list should obviously have a different `head` pointer, but there's nothing in the reversing algorithm that actually sets `head` to anything.

Comment: But linked list does have a different head pointer, i.e. in the base condition the last node becomes the head node

Comment: One of the best ways to trouble shoot linked lists is by drawing pictures. Make a simple list. Then step-by step redraw the list as you transform it into the new configuration. Use these drawings as the basis for your code. If you run into trouble, you follow your coded instructions exactly and if you don't get the exact same pictures, you've found the bug and probably have a good idea of what you should have done.

Comment: @SakshiTanwar if that were true, there would be a `head =` somewhere in `reverseListRecursive`. Since there isn't, what Sam says is true.

Comment: Danger: `if(head->next == nullptr)` does not cover the case where `head` itself is `nullptr`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik actually the basics of the algorithm  are ok, it can be easily fixed by adding a couple of lines do set `head`.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Can you please tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Your question should include a description of the symptoms (typically in the form of expected and actual results) so that others with the same problem have a reasonable chance to recognize that this question can help them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the head pointer needs to point to the last node of the linked list. Following code fixes the problem.

```
void reverseListRecursive(Node * &head, Node *temp = nullptr)
{
    if(temp == nullptr)
        temp = head;

    if(temp->next == nullptr)
    {
        head = temp;
        return;
    }

    reverseListRecursive(head, temp->next);

    temp->next->next = temp;
    temp->next = nullptr;

}
```